# How to validate formulas easily in Excel 2003?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

When reviewing Excel spreadsheets done by others, I have to do the work of validating all formulas contained in the workbook.

It's a frustrating, time-consuming process to trace the quoted cells, sometimes even in different sheets. I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> will only get back to one of the cells, if the formula contains several cells, i.e. `=A1*sheet1!B6`.

Is there a way to trace quickly back to all of them?

Comment: @pnuts I have checked the page, and i basically don't like using mouse, is there a key to simulate 'double-click' function? Also if i do like double click as instructed it doesn't go to or highlight the quoted cell in another sheet, if the formula contains both a cell in the current sheet, and other sheet.

Comment: Can't get xl2007, and it's standard setting in our office. D-click the dotted link to trace Precedents in another sheet won't lead directly to that quoted cell, what do you mean by displays the reference any?what appears to me is just a popup 'goto' dialogue box with the cell address in it,but doesn't turn the sheet, can i see the interface you see when you d-click dotted line？ P.S. I am writing in 'add comment' ,does @name format work in that?

Comment: @pnu true, i have reference both onsheet and offsheet, wait, when you say offsheet you mean really 'sheet' or workbook(another .xls file?) I am talking about only in the same workbook,no need to open a new file.

Comment: Also, rdgs, your select and press yes to go to the offsheet quote, i am thinking of a doubleclick on the dotted line would take me directly to that quoted cell, instead of choose the address of the pop up go-to window and click ok

Comment: @pnu I see your point, you mean maybe the offsheets quotes are multiple,and it will only have one dotted line for you to click upon right?Well, that's a lot of mouse clicks, and not efficient indeed, imagine i have been doing keyhits, and suddenly it requires to doubleclick and what's more, then click to select the address in 'goto'box, is there a way to replace mouse for select which address of offsheets item i want to go?